# Can not display the Product categories in Magento 2 Admin

Tags: product, category-products

I tryed to reduce the level of Shops in the installation as a helb.
Im quite new to the system.

I also change customer groups if that may be has a relaition.

Thanks for your problem solving replay ;-)

```
a:4:{i:0;s:225:"Notice: Undefined property: Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor::$storeManager in /home/taketime/public_html/shop/app/code/Plazathemes/Override/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit.php on line 97";i:1;s:6408:"#0 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/app/code/Plazathemes/Override/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit.php(97): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined prope...', '/home/taketime/...', 97, Array)
#1 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/app/code/Plazathemes/Override/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit.php(22): Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit->getStoreManager()
#2 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/var/generation/Plazathemes/Override/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit/Interceptor.php(25): Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit->execute()
#3 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->execute()
#4 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#8 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Plazathemes\\Ove...', 'dispatch', Object(Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#9 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Plazathemes\\Ove...', 'dispatch', Object(Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'designLoader')
#13 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php(39): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->aroundDispatch(Object(Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Plazathemes\\Ove...', 'dispatch', Object(Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#17 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#20 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/var/generation/Plazathemes/Override/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit/Interceptor.php(40): Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#21 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#24 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#26 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#29 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#30 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#32 /home/taketime/public_html/shop/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#33 {main}";s:3:"url";s:107:"/shop/nwkll9xw/catalog/category/index/key/61cba2613f4cf9dbf2e4526cf8da2b96932c43791906f3afe1add755d45b77ec/";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/shop/index.php";}
```

Comment: add code of `Plazathemes/Override/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit.php` file